# VBA code to sum a column in a changing Table with the sum above the header

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I'm new to VBA. My macro recorder created this code when I added a sum for each month at the top of my table above the Header. When the table grew the sum did not include the new lines at the bottom so I put 800 in there to ensure I have the correct value (my table has 540 rows of data right now).  This is a bandaid and I would like to fix the code so that it sums all values in the table for that column.  Then I autofilled the formula across all 12 months.

```
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[2]C:R[800]C)"
Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:T2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("H2:T2").Select
```

I found this:

```
Range("H4", Range("H1048576"),End(xlUp)).Select
```

which selects the right range for a table that is discontiguous and changes in size, but I don't know how to incorporate the Sum formula with this variable column range. Can someone help me with syntax?
Thanks!

Comment: `Range("H2:T2").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range("H4", Range("H1048576"),End(xlUp)).Address(0,0) & ")"`

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked perfectly once I corrected the , before the End to a period.  That was my typo.  I really do appreciate the help!